# Is NOT IN the same as <> in this context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Within the `where` clause of an SP I'm working on, I'm trying to filter out rows where there are matching `IDs`. Are there any differences in the below? Are there any benefits to either method? (I imagine the first option is quicker).

```
 - Where t1.ID <> t2.ID
 - Where t1.ID NOT IN (Select ID from T2)
```

Comment: Where does `t2` come from? Please show the entire queries.

Comment: @GMB the query is massive. However, T2 is coming from a left join. (Select...From T1 T1 left join T2 T2 on T1.id = T2.id)

Comment: based on the little information we  have, I would ***guess*** the first would effectively be a `CROSS JOIN` to `t2`; excluding matching rows, where as the latter would only return rows where there isn't a corresponding row. Also, neither would handle `NULL` values the same.

Answer (score 3):

I can only imagine one context where these would be the same.  That would be if `t2` had at most one different value of `id` in the table.

That seems highly unlikely, so I think the only reasonable answer is "no".

I suspect you are thinking of:

```
select . . .
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null;
```

This is almost equivalent to `not in` with a subquery.  (The only difference is if `id` is ever `NULL`.)